# How to iterate over array elements in scala

Tags: scala, sbt

Heads up, I'm new to Scala

```
object ch3
{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  {
    var foo =  Array (scala.io.StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt))
    foo.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Scenario:
The input contains 3 space separated integers read from stdin, like 
1 2 3. How can I iterate over that array and print the elements?

The problem is that when I try to print the array elements, I get this value [I@7ff9c904.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `scala.io.StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt)` is already an Array of Int. You're passing it to Array, which creates a new single-element array containing the output of map.

Just remove the outer Array.

```
var foo = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().split(" ").map(_.toInt)
foo.foreach(println)
```